# Pandas dataframe find distinct value count for each group in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Pandas` `dataframe` a sample input of which looks like below:

```
vendor  filename    language    score         text
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.67717278        text1  
Vendor 2    File 1  chinese 0.644506991       text2
Vendor 1    File 2  chinese 0.67717278        text1  
Vendor 2    File 1  chinese 0.644506991       text3
Vendor 1    File 2  Arabic 0.999999523        text3
Vendor 1    File 1  Arabic 0.756420255        text2
Vendor 2    File 3  Arabic 0.999999523        text4
Vendor 1    File 1  Arabic 0.756420255        text4
```

What I am trying to do is for each language and within that language for each file, count the distinct number of values in `text` column where `score` is greater than `0.5`. So my ideal output for above sample input should be:

```
Chinese  File 1  3
         File 2  1

Arabic   File 1  2
         File 2  1
         File 3  1
```

Note that `File 1` and `File 2` are both used by `Chinese` and `Arabic` but I want to count their unique text values separately for each language.

I tried to use `pandas` `groupby` and `unique` function in below code but this is not working as it throws error as `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'unique'`:

```
df_1 = df[df["score"] > 0.5].groupby(['language', 'filename']).unique().size()
    
print("Number of unique text greater than 0.5 score:{}".format(df_1))
```

What is the most ideal way to resolve this issue achieve the intended outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with specify column `text` for count number of unique values:

```
df_1 = df[df["score"] > 0.5].groupby(['language', 'filename'], sort=False)['text'].nunique()

print("Number of unique text greater than 0.5 score:\n{}".format(df_1))
Number of unique text greater than 0.5 score:
language  filename
chinese   File 1      3
          File 2      1
Arabic    File 2      1
          File 1      2
          File 3      1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```